# Как правильно отвалидировать доменную зону в емайл?

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно отвалидировать доменную зону в емайл?

как можно сделать чтобы после .com .ru .kz и тд больше не было других символов?

например

если test@gmail.commsdf3e43 то false

если test@gmail.com то true

---

какой вариант вижу я

делаю парсинг всех доступных доменных зоны, выбираю в емайл после собаки регуляркой доменную зону и проверяю есть ли она в массиве

Comment: А как специализированные определять будете? Типа .online или .cafe, их же уже тоннами создают... Как вариант, конечно, что Вы предлагаете, но это очень мутно.

Comment: Список всех существующих корневых зон https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: @VladimirGonchar а что то можно еще придумать? не подскажите?

Comment: Правильно: не надо ничего вилидировать. можете проверить наличие в адресе собаки. На этом все. после отправляете тестовое письмо. и ждете подтверждения. в email по стандартам может вообще не быть домена, а быть например Ip-адрес или что нибудь не англоязычное. `" "@xn--e1aigb.xn--p1ai` вполне себе корректный email .... хотя вам введут его в виде "мейл.рф" и будут то же  правы. потому что ваша почтовая система отлично сама справится с переводом в punycode

Comment: И интересно откуда разрешенные домены вы хотите  зановсить в массив. в наше время новые корневые домены появляются достаточно регулярно, значит вам надо будет скажем раз в день скачивать вот тот список что показали выше и обновлять свой массив для проверок